# Convert stored formula to work into PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have an stored formula into my database, that value is defined by some people in my organization and is used to calculate an average. The trouble is that I need to use that formula in a PL/pgSQL procedure (postgres), but the syntax is different, some formulas are like this:

```
if (x >= 0 && x <= 51.999) then 0 
elsif (x > 51.999 && x <= 64.999) then 70 
elsif (x > 64.999 && x <= 90.999) then 100 
elsif (x > 90.999 && x <= 103.999) then 115 
elsif (x > 103.999 && x <= 130) then 130 end
```

x = my value

I've been thinking about a replace, but I don't know if that would be the correct solution...
So, I need your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you could use a [`CASE` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE). Also change `&&` to `AND`.

Comment: Are you asking what the equivalent PSQL syntax would be, or are you asking how to convert the string that you have into a PSQL expression? In the latter case, what programming language are you using in your application? You probably shouldn't be doing this inside the database.

Comment: I need to convert that string into a plsql syntax, but that formula is variable, so can be. different from that. The app is in RoR, and I need to do it in plsql for the massive cases

Answer (score 1):

In PL/pgSQL syntax:

```sql
y := case
 when x between 0 and 51.999 then 0 
 when x between 52 and 64.999 then 70 
 when x between 65 and 90.999 then 100 
 when x between 91 and 103.999 then 115 
 when x between 104 and 130 then 130 
end;
```

Please note that `between` is inclusive. This is why I have changed the lower boundaries.
As a reusable function:

```sql
create or replace function custom_function(x numeric) returns numeric language sql as
$$
select case
 when x between 0 and 51.999 then 0 
 when x between 52 and 64.999 then 70 
 when x between 65 and 90.999 then 100 
 when x between 91 and 103.999 then 115 
 when x between 104 and 130 then 130 
end::numeric;
$$;
```

**Edit**
Multiple formulae. You can define/change many of them in a clean declarative way.

```sql
create or replace function pg_temp.custom_function(function_name text, x numeric)
returns numeric language sql as
$$
with function_data(fname, range_lo, range_hi, result) as
(
  values
  -- function_a parameter values
  ('function_a', 0,   51.999,  0),
  ('function_a', 52,  64.999,  70),
  ('function_a', 65,  90.999,  100),
  ('function_a', 91,  103.999, 115),
  ('function_a', 104, 130.999, 130),
  -- function_b parameter values 
  ('function_b', 0,   51.999,  10),
  ('function_b', 52,  64.999,  170),
  ('function_b', 65,  90.999,  200),
  ('function_b', 91,  103.999, 215),
  ('function_b', 104, 130.999, 230)
  -- other function names and values
)
select result::numeric 
  from function_data
  where fname = function_name 
  and x between range_lo and range_hi;
$$;
```

Call the function like this:

```sql
select custom_function('function_a', 100)
```

Comment: The trouble is that this function is a variable, some functions are like the one I put on, and others are different

Comment: Do they follow a similar pattern, i.e. return a single value for the argument in a range (in a staircase-like manner)?

Comment: Yes, every formula is very similar, evaluates a value in a range, and others are like "x*1"

Comment: I will append my answer